# Power Query Table.TransformColumnNames not recognised

Tags: rename, powerquery

I have a code line working fine in my computer, but when I send the file to my collegue, running Excel 2016, it's not working. The yellow box Error is saying something like Table.TransformColumnNames is not a recognised function.

Does anyone know why this could happen ?

The complete line code here :

`= Table.TransformColumnNames(TARGET, each "TARGET -  " & _)`

And if for some reason, no one can tell me why it's not working, can someone tell me another fontion to replace the Table.TransformColumnNames ? The only thing I want to to is to add the text string "TARGET - " at the beggining of all column names.

[image: Power Query Error]

THANK YOU !!

I want to understands why my code is not working in my collegue computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, but this would as well, so see if this does

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Rename=Table.RenameColumns(Source,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Source),List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each "TARGET -  " & _)}))   
in  Rename
```

Comment: Thank you again horseride. Your code is working exactly as the other one on my computer so I hope this time it will work on my collegue's computer.